# "Content Delivery third-party JAR file reference" of Tridion2013SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery

Please let me ask a question about "Content Delivery third-party JAR file reference" below.
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-7FC8BE58-FD55-4BC6-B2BE-26FC0C25013C

There was a doc defect below and it has been fixed in CRQ-4086.

***In SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, `hsqldb.jar 2.3.0`, `httpmime.jar 4.1.3`, `xalan.jar 2.7.1` are bundled.
However, the documentation below says `hsqldb.jar 2.2.8`, `httpmime.jar 4.1.2`, and `xalan.jar 1.3`.***

Correct jar version of those `hsqldb.jar`, `httpmime.jar` and `xalan.jar` could be checked in `MANIFEST.MF`.

However, there is no version information of following jar files in `MANIFEST.MF` of those.

- `jdbcpool.jar`
- `json-smart.jar`
- `sftp.jar`
- `easylicense.jar`

Question,
How can the correct version of `jdbcpool.jar`, `json-smart.jar`, `sftp.jar` and `easylicense.jar` be checked?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [DD4T BOM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/dd4t/dd4t-bom-2013SP1/2.1.0-beta/dd4t-bom-2013SP1-2.1.0-beta.pom) for 2013 SP1 or used in previous projects:

- json-smart: 1.1.1
- easylicense: 2.5
- sftp.jar: http://files.jscape.com/sftp/docs/html/index.html?introhistory.html. You can pick any, but probably it's 8.8.0 or 9.0.
- jdbcpool - 1.2.2

Comment: Hi Raimond,

Thank you for your response.

I looked at dd4t-bom-2013SP1-2.1.0-beta.pom you mentioned and could see json-smart-version is 1.1.1.
It means the documentation below is incorrect as it says json-smart.jar 1.0.
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-7FC8BE58-FD55-4BC6-B2BE-26FC0C25013C

I will raise a change request for it.

Is there any way to verify which version of jdbcpool.jar, sftp.jar and easylicense.jar are bundled in Tridion2013SP1?
In dd4t-bom-2013SP1-2.1.0-beta.pom, there is no information about those 3.

Comment: A couple of years ago I did a lot of research into this and the three mentioned jars are very old and not very well versioned. Changed the jdbcpool version btw.